# RNFIRMessaging static analyzer error

Tags: react-native, react-native-fcm

I am building an application using React native. Suddenly I encounter with **RNFIRMessaging** error. When open Xcode project from `xcworkspace` then it will say Semantic Issue. My code is working before. I don't know whats going on. **I reinstall all npm, check Header Search Path in Xcode. But nothing will work.**

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

[image: Ref Image]

Comment: Any solution for this issue?